# RDP Remote apps - can they share a single session?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, rdp, windows-terminal-services

I have a Windows server with couple of remote apps. When a user starts from his client a remote app, each of the apps is executed in a separate RDP session. I am mainly concerned about the login time. Is it possible for remote apps to share a single RDP session (so that further app logins are faster), or is it a fundamental limitation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that's the default, but it can be controlled with a `.rdp` setting (not available in GUI).

```
disableconnectionsharing:i:0
```

> Determines whether a new Terminal Server session is started with every
>   launch of a RemoteApp to the same computer and with the same
>   credentials.
>
> `0` – No new session is started. The currently active session of the
>   user is shared.
>
> `1` – A new login session is started for the RemoteApp.

See [Overview of .rdp file settings](https://www.donkz.nl/overview-rdp-file-settings/).